# How do I create a stack in a REST API?

Tags: rest, post, get, side-effects

I am working on a distributed execution server.  I have decided to use a REST API based on HTTP on the server.  The clients will connect to the server and GET the next task to be accomplished.  Obviously I need to "update" the task that is retrieved to ensure that it is only processed once.  A GET is not supposed to have any side effects (like changing the state of the resource retrieved).  I could use a POST (to update the resource), but I also need to retrieve it.  I am thinking that I could have a URL that a POST marks the task as "claimed", then a GET marks the task as retrieved.  Unfortunately I have a side effect on GET again.  Is this just not going to work in REST?  I am OK with have a "function" resource to do this, but don't want to give up the paradigm without a little research.

Pat O

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else fits, you're supposed to use a POST request. Nothing prevents you from returning the resource on a POST request. But it becomes apparent that something (in this case) will happen to that resource, which wouldn't be the case when using a GET request.

Answer (score -1):

REST is really just a concept, and you can implement it however you want. There is no one 'right way', as everyones use cases are different. (yes I understand that there is a defined spec out there, but you can still do it however you want) In this situation if your GET needs to have a side effect, it will have a side effect. Just make sure to properly document what you did (and potentially why you did it).

However it sounds like you're just trying to create a queue with multiple subscribers, and if the subscribers are automated (such as scripts or other machines) you may want to look at using an actual queue. (http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html).

If you are using this to power a web UI or something where actual people process this, you could also use a queue, with your GET request simply pulling the next item from the queue.

Note that when using most of the messaging systems you will not be able to guarantee the order in which the messages are pulled from the queue, so if the order is necessary you may not be able to use this approach.